# Python regex for finding unescaped characters

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a regex string that will (in Python) match only a character (let's say `:`) if it is not escaped. I also need it not to capture the backslashes if there's an even number of backslashes escaping each other, as I'm using it for find and replace.

There are a bunch of questions that this seems to duplicate, but it actually doesn't. That's because they either capture the backslashes, or don't work in Python `re`.

Some non-working regexes I've tried are `(?<!\\)(\\{2})*:` (captures backslashes), `(?<!(?:[^\\]|\A)(?:\\\\){0,1000}\\):`, and a couple other that won't work in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find and replace colons that are not escaped.

Use

```
result = re.sub(r'(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*):', r'\g<1>newstr', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqsYTR/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/10XHQE).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)` - no backslash right before the current location is allowed
- `((?:\\{2})*)` - *Capturing group 1*: 0 or more double backslash sequences
- `:` - a colon (replace with any char/pattern you need to replace)

In the replacement, the `\g<1>` (that is an unambiguous version of `\1`) backreference puts back the backslashes consumed with the Group 1 pattern. The `\g<1>` is more universal since you may replace the colon with a number/digit without issues.